# Calculate Discount from Price Levels in Netsuite Suitecommerce Advanced

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I'm trying to create a function in my ItemsKeyMapping.js that will calculate the percentage a customer will be saving on a product. I'm new to javascript and have been using tutorials. This is what I have:

```
// @property _DiscountPercent calculates the percentage between customers price and MSRP
    ,   _DiscountPercent: function (item)
        {
            var attributes = item.get('onlinecustomerprice') || ('pricelevel15');

            if ((pricelevel15 != 0) && (onlinecustomerprice != 0)) 

            {
                DiscountPercent = (1 - pricelevel15 / onlinecustomerprice) * 100;
            }
            else 
            {
             DiscountPercent = null;
             }
            return 'DiscountPercent';
        }
```

Anyone out there familar with SCA Mont Blanc that could help me finish this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post more of your code for context?

Comment: Hi Tony, There is a huge amount of code in SCA. What would help? 

This file is telling the back end to give the values for the onelnecustomer price and price level 15 on the item record. here is an example of another call requesting the information in a text field:

`// @property _StoreDescription grab the html in the web store description field
   , _StoreDescription: function(item)
    {
     return item.get('storedescription')
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
,   _DiscountPercent: function (item)
    {
        var normalPrice= item.get('onlinecustomerprice') 
        var discountedPrice= item.get('pricelevel15');
        var DiscountPercent = null;

        if ((discountedPrice > 0) && (normalPrice > 0)) 

        {
            DiscountPercent = (1 - discountedPrice / normalPrice) * 100;
        }

        return DiscountPercent;
    }
```

Comment: This looks much closer! haven't been able to get it working quite yet, not sure if I want onlinecustomer price or_priceDetails for example. I'll do some additional testing.